# How to get an last write time object using select-object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some folder, inside the folder there is a file and contain of ID, then I need to select one of the folder by last write time. I tried this way

```
  Function Test
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string]$Pattern
    )

    $global:Result = '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Exists'; Expression = {$false}}, FileName, Directory, @{Name = 'Attempts'; Expression = {1}}

    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($file) {
        $file = Get-Item -Path $file.Path 

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $file.FullName
            Directory = $file.DirectoryName
            Attempts  = 1
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Not Found"
    }
}


$ID = "8538"
$IDName = "ID_LST"
$Path = "D:\Folder\*\$IDName\"

Test -Path $Path -Pattern "$ID"
$global:Result | Format-List
```

The result is not select the folder based on the last write time, but based on the int of the folder name.

Comment: No, select object mean select the folder. The folder is in array, When I sort-the object  with this way `Sort-Object -Property {$_.LastWriteTime}` looks like this `Directory : {D:\3DT601, D:\3DT501, D:\6BW602, D:\6BT602}`

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to use `$global` variables because the function simply outputs the (array) of objects.

Also, I would recommend changing the function name to comply with the `Verb-Noun` convention.

Something like this should work:

```
function Test-Pattern { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Pattern
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Filter '*.*' | ForEach-Object {
        if (Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists        = $true
                FileName      = $_.FullName
                Directory     = $_.DirectoryName
                LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
                Attempts      = 1
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Pattern '$Pattern' not found in file $($_.FullName)"
        }
    }
}

$ID     = "8538"
$IDName = "ID_LST"
$Path   = "D:\Folder\*\$IDName"

# now use the function to find files that contain the pattern
# and capture the result in a variable.
$result = Test-Pattern -Path $Path -Pattern $ID

# output on screen
$result | Format-List

# output to csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\patternsearch.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not what you want need then Please let me know.  I do my best to understand. This does not work right now but, I have some questions.  What is in $SSID?  Is your goal to find wireless SSIDs in a folder?

```
Function Test
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)] # Postion = 2 needs be Postion = 1
        [string]$Pattern
    )

    # It looks you are making an object twice.  You do not need this.  The PSCustomObject will do the job
    # $global:Result = '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Exists'; Expression = {$false}}, FileName, Directory, @{Name = 'Attempts'; Expression = {1}}

    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  # | Select-Object -First 1  # We will need more than one so we can sort it.

    if ($file) {

    Foreach ($f in $file) {  # Feed one object at a time to make your PSObject. 
        $myfile = Get-Item -Path $f.Path 

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $myfile.FullName
            Directory = $myfile.DirectoryName
            LastWriteTime = $myfile.LastWritetime
            Attempts  = 1   # attempts will always equal 1 # I do not know what you are trying to do but, it will not break code.
            }
            $global:Result # output one object a time.
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Not Found"
    }
}

Test <# I help with the input to the fuction #> | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime


<#
$ID = "8538"
$IDName = "ID_LST"
$Path = "D:\Folder\*\$IDName\"

Test-FileWithGui -Path $Path -Pattern "$SSID"
$global:Result | Format-List
#>
```

Comment: sorry, typo it means `$ID`

Comment: Give me an example of an ID and pattern?

Comment: it looks like the sort by last write time not working.
Here are the output of the folder I have and the last write time

Comment: `Exists        : True
FileName      : D:\10601\ID_LST
Directory     : D:\10601
LastWriteTime : 3/27/2020 11:35:42 AM
Attempts      : 1

Exists        : True
FileName      : D:\11601\ID_LST
Directory     : D:\11601
LastWriteTime : 3/27/2020 11:00:17 AM
Attempts      : 1

Exists        : True
FileName      : D:\18601\ID_LST
Directory     : D:\18601
LastWriteTime : 3/27/2020 11:01:51 AM
Attempts      : 1`

Comment: it return this folder as a lastwritetime `Exists        : True
FileName      : D:\18601\ID_LST
Directory     : D:\18601
LastWriteTime : 3/27/2020 11:01:51 AM
Attempts      : 1`

but if we see the lastwrite time, it should be choose this folder `Exists        : True
FileName      : D:\11601\ID_LST
Directory     : D:\11601
LastWriteTime : 3/27/2020 11:00:17 AM
Attempts      : 1`

Comment: The $Pattern is the $ID, which is `$ID = "8538"`